# Extra registers in x86 64 bit

Tags: c, linux, 64-bit, x86

I have written my own **setjmp/longjmp** which fits my needs, as shown below. I tested it on 32 bit systems and it works good. I save and restore registers eax, ebx, ecx, edi, esi, esp, ebp and eip for that purpose.

However, I know, this would not be enough for a 64 bit system. First of all, I think I need to replace registers eX with rX. Secondly, I think I need to save the 8 extra registers found in x86-64 bit, which are  r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15. Would that be enough, or do I need to do more?

```
#define MY_SETJMP(n) __asm__ __volatile__ ("movl %eax, regax"#n";" \
     "movl %ebx, regbx"#n";" \
     "movl %ecx, regcx"#n";" \
     "movl %edi, regdi"#n";" \
     "movl %esi, regsi"#n";" \
     "movl %esp, regsp"#n";" \
     "movl %ebp, regbp"#n";" \
     "call next"#n";" \
     "next"#n": pop regip"#n";" \
     "addl $6, regip"#n";" \
     )

#define MY_LONGJMP(n) __asm__ __volatile__ ("movl regax"#n", %eax;" \
     "movl regbx"#n", %ebx;" \
     "movl regcx"#n", %ecx;" \
     "movl regdi"#n", %edi;" \
     "movl regsi"#n", %esi;" \
     "movl regsp"#n", %esp;" \
     "movl regbp"#n", %ebp;" \
     "jmp *regip"#n";" \
     )
```

Comment: Why did you write your own instead of using the _working_ system one?

Comment: Like I said, I am using it for a special purpose, which couldn't be done using the existing setjmpt/longjmp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your sequence of instruction does not save the [flags register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29), which it probably should even in IA32. The wikipedia page contains the instructions `pushf` and `popf` that you can use to do so.

You need to save all the vector registers, unless you know that the program doesn't use them. Beware: they can also be used for scalar floating-point, so you do not need to have vectorized code in your program for them to be in use.
Oh, and if the program uses floating-point, you should save the historical floating-point stack in case that is used. Dan Kruchinin's answer shows how to save all these in one step.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you need to save x87 context as well using fxsave/fxrestore instructions: http://siyobik.info/main/reference/instruction/FXSAVE

Though, I'm not sure fxsave/fxresrtore can be safely used from user-space application (i.e. outside of supervisor mode), but you can do almost everything fxsave does by yourself.

Comment: Why do you think that fxsave can be unsafe in user-space? It is not privileged instruction, as i know.